# Exception when saving print document to XPS

Tags: c#, printing

Am saving my Print document as XPS in My application start up path using the code

```
*PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd = PreparePrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Application.StartupPath+"\\backup.xps";
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
pd.Print();
pd.Dispose();*
```

this works fine in some PC's but in some the following error occurs

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

when i set the default printer to XPS the code works in all systems.but when i change it to network printer the error occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument()) 
{
    pd = PreparePrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = 
    Application.StartupPath+"\\backup.xps";
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "XPS";
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName ="Microsoft XPS Document Writer"        
    pd.Print();
}
```